# Lightdm(with slick-greeter) only starts AFTER tty login

Tags: login, xorg, lightdm, login-screen, auto-login

I recently installed slick-greeter, and have wrestled with various configuration issues, and spent quite some time searching various threads across various distros for the issue I'm seeing.

That is, when I first boot, I am met with a completely black screen.  However, when I swiitch to a TTY (all I have to do is switch to a TTY, I don't manually start the service or log in or anything), I can press `ctrl + alt + f7` and the greeter starts successfully. When I check the `lightdm` status with `systemctl`, it says it's running nominally- however, I'm not sure how I'd find whatever errors existed prior to my login.

I checked the lightdm and xorg logs, and didn't see anything obvious, though I'm not experienced searching those particular logs. This makes me think the issue is tied to my user login somehow.

Do you all have any suggestions for further troubleshooting/mitigating?

```
sean@:~$ lightdm --show-config
   [Seat:*]
A  allow-guest=false
C  greeter-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-greeter-session
D  guest-wrapper=/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session
E  greeter-session=slick-greeter
F  xserver-command=X -core

   [LightDM]
B  backup-logs=false

Sources:
A  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-guest.conf
B  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-disable-log-backup.conf
C  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-greeter-wrapper.conf
D  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-guest-wrapper.conf
E  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-slick-greeter.conf
F  /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-xserver-command.conf
```

Comment: Likely you just are not waiting long enough for the greeter to start.  Or you are somehow watching the wrong virtual console and just need to hit alt-F7 sooner.

Comment: I'll try waiting longer, it's not the wrong tty though. I'll update this comment with the results.

EDIT: It's not a matter of waiting. Whether I wait 2 minutes or immediately log in via tty, `lightdm` starts immediately after I log in via TTY.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)